# view slide (follow finger position vertically up/down) with uipangesturerecognizer and auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uipangesturerecognizer

this is a very simple problem but i can't figure it out. first, here is how the views are added as sub view and I'm using Autolayout. the (black) root view contains blue colored and orange coloured views. the orange coloured view is the tops most which partly covers the blue view. the button in orange view has pan gesture recognizer. i got it working if gestures ends then orange view positions itself properly.( either just like in the photo covering the blue view, or orange can be slided down till only the orange is visible.) the orange view's position is only changed vertically using autolayout constant.

[image]

the issue I'm facing is that if one pans up and down `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` then it happens that the orange view  slides to the opposite direction of panning. how to change the auto layout constant properly? the orange view's range of vertical movement is from starting point like in the sketch downward till that orange button remains visible.

```
#define MIN_SIZE 50
   -(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) pan
   {
   CGFloat viewHeight = pan.view.superview.height; //superView is the big orange view
if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    self.startLocation = [pan locationInView:self.view];
}

if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint stopLocation = [pan locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat dist = sqrt(pow((stopLocation.x - self.startLocation.x), 2) + pow((stopLocation.y - self.startLocation.y), 2));

    if (velocityOfPan.y > 0)
    {
        if (self.verticalConstraint.constant >= viewHeight - MIN_SIZE)
        {
            self.verticalConstraint.constant = viewHeight - MIN_SIZE;
        }
        else
            self.verticalConstraint.constant = dist;
    }
    else if(velocityOfPan.y < 0)
    {
        if (self.verticalConstraint.constant <= 0)
        {
            self.verticalConstraint.constant = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            self.verticalConstraint.constant = (viewHeight - MIN_SIZE - dist);
        }
    }
}
else if(pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    if (velocityOfPan.y > 0)
    {
        self.verticalConstraint.constant = viewHeight - MIN_SIZE;

    }
    else if (velocityOfPan.y < 0)
    {
        self.verticalConstraint.constant = 0;
    }

}

[self updateViewAnimation];
}
}

-(void) updateViewAnimation
{
[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6 initialSpringVelocity:-1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some searching and reading I found out what I was doing wrong. Here is how I solved it, just in case somebody else wanna know it.

```
-(void)(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) pan
{
CGPoint velocityOfPan = [pan velocityInView:self.view];
CGFloat viewHeight = pan.view.superview.height;

CGPoint delta;
switch(pan.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        self.startLocation = delta = [pan translationInView:self.view];
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
    {
        delta = CGPointApplyAffineTransform([pan translationInView:self.view], CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.startLocation.x, -self.startLocation.y));
        self.startLocation = [pan translationInView:self.view];

        if(delta.y < 0 && self.verticalConstraint.constant < 0)
        {
            delta.y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            delta.y = self.verticalConstraint.constant + delta.y;
        }
        self.verticalConstraint.constant = delta.y;
        [self updateViewAnimation];
        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    {
        if (velocityOfPan.y > 0)
        {
            delta.y = (viewHeight - MIN_SIZE);

        }
        else if(velocityOfPan.y < 0)
        {
            delta.y = 0;
        }
        self.verticalConstraint.constant = delta.y;
        [self updateViewAnimation];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
}
```